# NVM managed npm globally installed packages return command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

I have nvm installed to manage my node versions. If I install a package globally, `npm install -g fkill`, then run `fkill`, I get the error `zsh: command not found: fkill`.

Here are some commands run to help with debugging this

```
$ npm root -g
/home/jchi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules
```

Looking at my PATH...

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/jchi/.pyenv/shims:/home/jchi/.pyenv/bin:/home/jchi/.nix-profile/bin:/home/jchi/.autojump/bin:/home/jchi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

I do not see the output of `npm root -g` in my PATH.

I assume is nvm's responsibility to add that to my path so globally installed packages can be run. So I look at what I have in my `.zshrc` that kickstarts nvm.

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
  105 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Looking at your PATH, you do have the nvm bin folder under your PATH. 
`/home/jchi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin`

I would suggest to check if you have **prefix** related settings in `~/.npmrc`.

If you have any **prefix** settings, please remove it.

Then try running `npm install -g fkill` again.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same situation and also there is no prefix in .npmrc. any suggestion?

Comment: Hey, could you describe a bit more regarding your situation?

Comment: Hi, I had this exact prefix entry in my npmrc config file and your solution worked like a charm. And global npm packages fall under the correct installed nvm node version, thank you.

Comment: It's 2024 and I'm glad I found this as I have been trying to figure out why global installs won't go into the current nvm node version. Instead, it always goes to an older version. Turns out a prefix is in the .npmrc file. Removing it works as it should and npm root -g now points to the correct version. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is to add your NVM node bin to your path.

1. What node version are you using? `node --version`
2. Add the line below to your `.bashrc` (replace VERSION with what you got in step 1)

```
export PATH="$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/VERSION/bin:$PATH"
```

**Example:**

```
export PATH="$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v16.1.0/bin:$PATH"
```

3. When you refresh your terminal (`. ~/.bashrc` or re-opening terminal), your global Node commands should work now.

Unfortunately, it seems this needs to be done for each version of Node you use.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a package (let's call it `cat-hat`) installed globally on Node 14 using NVM (verified by checking `.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/lib/node_modules/cat-hat`) but I was getting `zsh: command not found` when trying to run it in my command line.

The issue in my case was that `cat-hat` only runs OK on node versions below 13. This can be verified in the package.json engines.node field.

I fixed this by changing to node 12, and installing `cat-hat` again for v12, and it worked as expected.